# Can not add the Add to cart button text in woocommerce of wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, button, product

I add the “Add to cart” text using this following code. There can see the button text in mobile.

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.wooaddtocart-shopping-cart.disabled.wc-variation-selection-needed:before{
    content: "Add to cart";
    color: red;
}

button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.wooaddtocart-shopping-cart:before{
    content: "Add to cart";
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6KTF.png)

There can see the color blur of the text

Answer (score 0):

```
.button::before {
  content: "Add to cart";
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```